# DNS: Can a URL that looks like a subdirectory be mapped to a different IP address?

Tags: internet, dns, ip-address

If my website `blah.example.com` has an IP address of `X.X.X.X`, then can I have a URL that *appears* to be a subdirectory, such as `blah.example.com/fizz`, be mapped to a totally different IP address (say, `Y.Y.Y.Y`)?

If not, why? If so, how and what kindo of DNS configuration does this require?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this, there are *similar* solutions you can do (redirect, virtual directories, ect...) that may work, but we need to know more about what you are trying to accomplish to be able to tell you which one will solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

This is because the part that deals with IPs (DNS) does not know anything about the request URL.

When your web browser tries to go to `blah.example.com/fizz`, it first pings the DNS server and asks who `blah.example.com` is, and gets back `X.X.X.X`. It then asks `X.X.X.X` for `/fizz`.

The problem is the DNS server (which translates `blah.exmaple.com` into `X.X.X.X`) never hears about the `/fizz` part of the URL at all, so it cannot return a different IP for it.

It *can* return a different ip for a different subdomain, though:

```
     blah.example.com -> X.X.X.X
fizz.blah.example.com -> Y.Y.Y.Y
```